# Create dataset in R to test stopifnot()

Tags: r, testing

I am looking to test several stopifnot() I put into a function I built.  It is checking for length(), is.numeric(), is.finite(), etc.  I need to create a dataset in R that I can test all of these on. I am struggling to create a valid table(or something similar) in order to be able to test.

```
x <- dataset #this is what I need to make

myfun <- function(x)
{
  stopifnot(length(x) > 0)
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
  stopifnot(is.finite(x))

  return(123)
}
```

Comment: Please include testing code that you have written

Comment: So what are you asking? How to apply your function to a dataset? How to create a test dataset? How to have the function return a *"table(or something similar)"*?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, I am asking how to create a test dataset.

Comment: What data type is the argument of `myfun` supposed to be? A `scalar`, `vector`, `data.frame`, `list`, `matrix`, ...? I'm still not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  It can be any of those.  I tried data.frame and list, but I couldn't figure out how to make either without making all of the elements finite and numeric.  Hence, I cannot tell if my stopifnot(is.numeric) and is.finite actually work.

Comment: @RADO is `x <- 1` a valid answer? It will work. Or do you want it to fail? Then `x <- NULL` or `x <- "A"` will do. You really need to clarify what you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.

Here I generate a sample `list`, `data.frame` and `vector`, and show the output of `myfun` based on those different input objects.

```
# Sample list
lst <- list(
    a = NA,
    b = "text",
    c = 1:10);

# Sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:10,
    b = letters[1:10]);

# Sample vector  
vec <- c(1:5, Inf, 7:10);

myfun(lst);
#Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE

myfun(df);
#Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE

myfun(vec);
#Error: is.finite(x) are not all TRUE
```

Obviously you can change your input objects to test for different conditions.